# Where can I get brown packing paper mesh?

Tags: paper

I've been working on a collage with some packaging paper that I received in a shipment from somewhere and I'd like to get some more.  There are some pictures of this kind of paper in Google Images and it is referred to as [Brown Packaging Paper mesh](http://www.123rf.com/photo_36470125_closeup-of-brown-paper-packaging-cut-to-create-a-mesh.html):

[image: brown packing mesh paper]

Wondering whether anyone here might have some suggestions as to how I could get some more of this.

Comment: Thanks for naming the material. Target ships (2021) items using this brown mesh, but I don’t think they sell it. It seems a bit stretchy & probably expensive. I’m trying to figure out what to make from it that won’t collect dust.

Answer (score 4):

When I want larger volumes of packing material, I tend to look to two sources:

1. Self-storage facilities. A lot of these places offer boxes and other packing/storage material and may offer cardboard options as opposed to traditional bubble wrap.
2. Self-moving companies like U-haul, amongst others, who can supply a lot of the basic packing and storage material for a move.

Beyond that, office supply like Grand & Toy, Staples, etc. would be next on my list. Actually, given some convenience, they might be first. :)

Comment: Thanks John,  I just haven't seen what seems to be called "mesh" as pictured on Google Images if you search for Brown Packing Paper Mesh.

Comment: @SteveWilson - I think you may be searching with the wrong terms... http://www.staples.com/Caremail-Greenwrap-/product_737645

Comment: You might also try shipping companies -- UPS & FedEx bought Kinkos & Mailboxes, Etc, (I don't remember which is which) so now have stores in various shopping centers.  (I take my styrofoam peanuts to the UPS store near me)

Answer (score 4):

This is the Geami Wrappak by Ranpak industries. It's an ecofriendly packaging solution made of die cut kraft paper and tissue paper.

Comment: Do you know where you can get it?